# Swift - Can I achieve mutual generics reference to classes?

Tags: swift, generics, nested-generics

I want to have two classes that are bound. This means, both classes know about each other methods.

```
BaseController <> BaseView
```

Those classes are used to declare subclasses, for example

```
LoginController <> LoginView.
```

`BaseController` has a strong reference to its view of kind `<T : BaseView>`, `BaseView` should have a weak reference to its controller of kind `<T: BaseController>`

I have managed to have a generic to BaseView:

```
  class BaseController <T: BaseScreen>
```

so that I do:

```
 class LoginController : BaseController<LoginView>
```

that works and the controller has direct access (visibility) to the view functions and I don't need to cast every time.

However I cannot do the same on the View, because if I do

```
 class BaseView <T : BaseController>
```

Then the compiler forces me to do

```
class BaseView <T : BaseController <BaseScreen>>
```

Which results in a recursion error.

Is there a way I can do that cross reference using generics? Right now I'm sticking with the view simply casting to the Controller in case it is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use protocols and associated types instead of base classes (and implement the methods of the base type in a protocol extension):

```
protocol ControllerProtocol: class {
    associatedtype View: ViewProtocol
    var view: View { get }
}
protocol ViewProtocol: class {
    associatedtype Controller: ControllerProtocol
    weak var controller: Controller { get }
}
```

A class implementing one of the protocols has to specify a typealias to the desired related class:

```
class LoginController: ControllerProtocol {
    typealias View = LoginView
    var view: LoginView
    ...
}

class LoginView: ViewProtocol {
    typealias Controller = LoginController
    weak var controller: LoginController
    ...
}
```

Comment: Great! I still need the superclass because it has some method implementations, but I think I can also protocols

Comment: You could also still use the base classes and use the protocols only for the type specific stuff.